# What is the meaning of xs, md, lg in CSS Flexbox system?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-flexbox-grid

I'm developing an application using `React` and wanted to style components, I found https://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/ which talks about a fluid grid system. The example looks like:

```
<Row>
  <Col xs={12} sm={3} md={2} lg={1} />
  <Col xs={6} sm={6} md={8} lg={10} />
  <Col xs={6} sm={3} md={2} lg={1} />
</Row>
```

and I do not know what is `xs`, `sm` and `lg` is? Could someone please explain?

Comment: its the measure of how much column space each `col` takes on different screen sizes. xs -> extra small, sm -> small, md -> medium, lg -> large. See that each size totals up to `12`(the number of columns the screen is divide into)

Comment: Thanks, if I do column wise adddition, `xs` column sums to `24` and not 12, does it means 2 rows? where 1st col takes the full row  and 2nd and 3rd col fits in second row with 50% width each?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Let us assume that our screen is divided into `12` columns.

The `xs` part takes up when screen is extra small, Similarly small, medium and large classes as well, based on their respective screen size definition in CSS.

The example you provided:

```
<Row>
  <Col xs={12} sm={3} md={2} lg={1} />
  <Col xs={6} sm={6} md={8} lg={10} />
  <Col xs={6} sm={3} md={2} lg={1} />
</Row>
```

For our sake lets assume these three columns are named as `col-1`, `col-2` and `col-3`

**On an extra small screen:**

`col-1` takes up all the 12 columns and the rest two of them take 6 each(on a new row)
[image]

**On small screens**

`col-1` and `col-3` takes up 3, while the middle one `col-2` takes 6
[image]

### Similarly

**Medium screens**
[image]

**Large screens**
[image]

**P.S.** Images are screenshots of the link you provided (by resizing the browser for each screen size)

Comment: Can we write css styles inside xs, e.g.   xs={{width : "100px"}}

Comment: @YuvrajMule I think no. for custom responsive you can write in your own css file

Answer (score 17):

[React Flexbox Grid](https://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/) can be used to make your website responsive. It is derived from the grid system followed by [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

The grid system divides the screen into 12 columns and you can mention how much width can be taken for components in mobile devices, tablets and desktops. The breakpoints for `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg` and `xl` are 576px, 768px, 992px and 1200px.

You can see the difference by resizing the browser window of the page https://roylee0704.github.io/react-flexbox-grid/

Its same as the below media query

```
// xs --- Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

// sm --- Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// md --- Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// lg --- Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// xl --- Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, if I do column wise adddition, xs column sums to 24 and not 12, does it means 2 rows? where 1st col takes the full row and 2nd and 3rd col fits in second row with 50% width each?

Comment: Yes.. In the code snippet in your question, `xs` columns will take 2 rows in small devices as you mentioned.

Comment: I hope i have clarified your doubt

Comment: Yes you did! Thanks a lot