# What does xs in Grid mean

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What does the `xs` in the following code mean?

```
              <Grid item xs>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  Forgot password?
                </Link>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                  {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                </Link>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

The line of code is from  https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.6.1/docs/data/material/getting-started/templates/sign-in/SignIn.js

Comment: It refers to [breakpoints](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/) for responsive design.

Comment: The `xs` is specify the column's width. In this context, with no value assigned, it means `Auto Layout`. Read this for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fDzCWNS3ig&ab_channel=TheWeekndVEVO

Answer (score 5):

See [the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#fluid-grids).

> Column widths are integer values between 1 and 12; they apply at any breakpoint and indicate how many columns are occupied by the component.
>
> A value given to a breakpoint applies to all the other breakpoints wider than it (unless overridden, as you can read later in this page). For example, `xs={12}` sizes a component to occupy the whole viewport width regardless of its size.

When you don't pass any associated value for the xs prop, [you get](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#auto-layout):

> Auto-layout
>
> The Auto-layout makes the items equitably share the available space. That also means you can set the width of one item and the others will automatically resize around it.

The example they give is

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid item xs>
    <Item>xs</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    <Item>xs=6</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs>
    <Item>xs</Item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Remember how the maximum column width is 12; having one xs of 6 and two auto widths means that the two widths become 3.

So your

```
<Grid item xs>
```

means that that component will attempt to take up whatever space is available, shared with other components with auto-layout.

Comment: Thanks, that what i was looking for, I didn't find any places in the documentation saying xs without value refer to auto, or does it?

Comment: See [the link I put in the answer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#auto-layout)

Comment: I see..it's shown in the code..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using grid to provide different layouts, we use  xs, sm, md, lg, and xl to determine our breakpoints. We can distribute our grid in 12 columns and give different designs to them based on our usage.

`xs` is used for phones. If I have put xs={12} this means I want the entire width of the component. Similarly if I put xs={6}, then it will mean I want half area of the component and so on

Answer (score 0):

`xs` refers to the column width on a device with an *extra small* screen - typically a phone. To control column widths on all sizes of device, each grid element can also specify column widths for `sm`, `md`, `lg` and `xl` sized screens.

A more complete explanation can be in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43446554/636375).

Answer (score -1):

`xs` is usually an acronym for `extra small`.

Comment: Although that's true, it doesn't explain why MaterialUI supports an integer value associated with it.